# How do you include a linebreak taken from a textarea in a paragraph?

Tags: c#, jquery, css, html

I am using a textarea in my view page to store information in a database, then retrieve it to put in a paragraph. Sometimes I have to include a new line in the textarea, but it is always stored in the database as "a b c", when i retrieve the data to put into a paragraph the new line does not appear. It always shows in a horizontal format like "a b c". How can i show the same  style in paragraph format?

Comment: You need to at least show the code you have tried. So we have something to work with :) You have tagged this question with `C#` as well as `jQuery`, so we need to know what you are trying to do. Is it an MVC Razor page?

Comment: How is the newline stored in database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you read the text from the database and before you show it in the paragraph, you will need to replace the newlines with HTML line breaks.

```
string text = textFromDatabase.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the textarea wrapped in pre tag

```
<pre><textarea>CONTENT 
CONTENT
</textarea></pre>
```

Comment: Have you got a reference for this? What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use Pre tag to display the data this will consider the line breaks as entered in the textarea you dont need to put textarea inside pre tag as mentioned in the answer of @user3820407

```
<pre>
 Your Text 
</pre>
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="paragraph">

</p>
<script>
    var ContentFromTextArea = "Your text area content goes here.";
    ContentFromTextArea.replace("\r", "<br />");
    ContentFromTextArea.replace("\n", "<br />");
    $("#paragraph").html(ContentFromTextArea);
</script>
```